# Copying an Access Report into Word

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

So I created this Access database with two tables, Person and Project - a person can have multiple projects. I created an Access Report which contains the data of every person and every project per person. Now I need a VBA script that copies the data of the report into a Word file that already has already content in it. I've looked around but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Can you convert the report to a word doc, then insert doc into the doc via vba?  so c:\tmpReport.docx is inserted into c:\template.docx

Comment: Do you know how I would get the content of the generated file and put it at the end of template? Also do you know if it is possible to put the generated data inside a table? Since a report "table" won't be exported to the word file

Comment: There's no VBA that can directly transfer the report into the Word document. The report can be exported for Word (use an Access macro for that, or VBA). That will create an RTF file which can be inserted into Word.

If you want to transfer all the data to Word, using VBA, then you'll need to automate Word and write the data explicitly. There are plenty of code samples on the Internet for automating Word and plenty of code samples for picking data out of your database. Some (old) sample code is available on my website: http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/mergfaq1.htm#ComplexMerg

Comment: You'll also need code for creating and formatting tables. Here's one resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simple method . . .

DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "NameOfReport", "RichTextFormat(*.rtf)", "C:\WINDOWS\NameOfWhatYouWantWordDoc.doc", True, ""

Or, take a look at one of these links.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/export-reports-to-ms-word-using-vba.2086498/

http://www.devhut.net/2012/04/23/ms-access-vba-export-records-to-ms-word/